# Amazon EC2 npm update for many instances

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, npm, circleci

I have many Amazon EC2 instances running. There is one node application for each instance. Each instance has a github private module installed.

When I update a module, how can I do kind of `npm update` for all services without connecting each by hands?

One way to do this is to rebuild project with circleci, but that takes a lot of time. Is there any way to do it faster?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CircleCI API to trigger a build with the upstream app from each of the modules.

Another method would be the change your infrastructure to use something like AWS ECS to manage updates with multiple services and nodes.